# Chrome extansion "default_icon" strange orange background

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I am trying to add button to extension like in tutorial here - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

```
"browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.png" }
```

But the result is strange, icon has orange background, it became transparent only when hovered.
Icons from other extensions don't have this problem:

[image: strange background]

[Icon itself](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/getstarted/icon.png) is from tutorial

What can be wrong here?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before on s.o.

Answer (score 0):

It was in development mode, when I packed extension, the problem has gone.

Comment: Clarification: it was loaded as an unpacked extension, on Windows, in release/beta versions of Chrome. Currently, no other version of Chrome exhibits this behavior.